# How to check if PasswordFor is empty

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have TextBoxFor and PasswordFor in Razor, I want to check using js if both of them are filled with some data?

My code works, but only in case when there are two TextBoxes. How to make it works also for PasswordFor?

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Login, new {@class = "form-control", @id="tekst1"})
 @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new {@class = "form-control", @id="tekst2"})


     <script type="text/javascript">

    function disableButtons() {
        $("input[type='submit']").attr("disabled", true);
    }

    function enableButtons() {
        $("input[type='submit']").attr("disabled", false);
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        disableButtons();

        var $textInputs = $('input[type="text"],textInputs');
        $('input').on('change', function () {

            var anyEmpty = $textInputs.filter(function () { return this.value == ""; }).length > 0;
            if (!anyEmpty) {
                enableButtons();
            } else {
                disableButtons();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please show us all the relevant code (and properly formatted).

Comment: It is not pure _html_. Please edit your tags.

Comment: There is no such element as `textbox`, so you can remove that from your selectors. Then just change your selector for `$textInputs` to be `$('input')`. Password fields have `type="password"` on them, which obviously `type="text"` won't match.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I have editted it, but probably I didn't understend you properly because buttons still enable if I only enter something in login

Comment: That's not HTML, that's Razor (C#)

Comment: @jeuxjeux20 thanks ;)

Comment: Wht are you not just adding a `[Required]` attribute to your property (and other validation attributes as required) and include `@Html.ValidationMesageFor(m => m.xxx)` so that you get both client and server side validation out of the box

Comment: @Karolina you're welcome ;) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Razor code:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Login, new {@class = "form-control", @id="tekst1"})
@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new {@class = "form-control", @id="tekst2"})
```

renders something like this to the browser:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="tekst1">
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="tekst2">
```

(it likely also renders a label and possibly other attributes, but these are the important bits).

When you run the following code:

```js
var $textInputs = $('input[type="text"],textInputs');
```

jQuery looks for elements like:

```html
<input type="text" (any other attributes)>
<textInputs></textInputs>
```

As you can see, `<input type="password" class="form-control" id="tekst2">` does not match either pattern. So, the only thing in `$textInputs` is:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="tekst1">
```

If you've entered a value into that input, then after the filter:

```js
$textInputs.filter(function () { return this.value == ""; }).length
```

will be equal to 0 and therefore `anyEmpty` will be `false` and `enableButtons` will be called.

If you want to find all `input` elements that are empty, regardless of their `type` attribute, change the line to:

```js
var $textInputs = $('input');
```

Or, you could do all of this in a single function, like:

```js
$(function() {
  $(':input:not(:button):not(:submit)').on('change', function() {
    $(':submit').prop('disabled', $(':input:not(:button):not(:submit)').filter(function(el) {
      el.value === '';
    }).length > 0);
  });
});
```

Note that `':input:not(:button):not(:submit)'` is a selector that will match all form elements except buttons, while `':submit'` matches only submit buttons. See [jQuery's documentation on form selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/form-selectors/).

Comment: You should probably start learning what ASP.NET MVC's tag helpers emit, and how jQuery (and CSS) selectors work. Trust me, it pays in the long run.